# extend spring web flow 2.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I'm working on a project with Spring Web Flow to manage some configurable flows.

My main question is: is it possible to extend the framework with custom classes and extend the spring-webflow-2.0.xsd?

We need to change the default behaviour of Spring Web Flow to achieve the following goals:

1. Extend the spring-webflow-2.0.xsd in order to add custom elements we need within the "states". And so, extend also the XmlFlowModelBuilder class in order to parse these new custom elements.
2. We need to be able to set a custom builder (like flow-builder inside flow-registry) which reads several XML resources, each one with its own id, like flow-location-pattern does. So we need a kind of mix between both ways to define a flow-registry. In addition, we would like to get those XML flow definition files from an external source (eg, with a service), and auto-rebuild the flowModels when some of those external XML changes.

Is it possible? We have found out that the flow-registry element creates a FlowRegistryFactoryBean, which has the main method calls. We would like to customize the class but this is not possible since it is a private class. We cannot even create a bean with this class.

So how could we make these customizations?

Answer (score 0):

As in any other case of using the java library, you can extend and compose the classes from `spring-webflow` packages.